# In what efficient way does MyISAM/InnoDB deletes specific text from a file?

Tags: c, database, file, innodb, myisam

Please read the whole question before marking it as duplicate.

I know that we have only one way to remove a specific text from a file in C i.e. by rewriting the whole file except the text that we want to delete.But this method will not be very efficient if we have a file with thousands or millions of lines of text. Now since MyISAM is a storage engine which has to be made efficient because it is to be used for millions of records and it is made in C,so how does it accomplishes this without rewriting the whole file again?i.e. I am asking the technique which the developers of MyISAM used to delete a specific text from file without rewriting it again.

Comment: Not marking as duplicate, but vtc as 'too broad' instead.  We cannot take on explaining databases:(

Comment: @MartinJames can you please explain in short. I am just asking for the solution that was used by the developers to overcome the problem of rewriting the file.

Comment: agree with @MartinJames. Impossible in short answer. MySQL engine is effect of many years and many developers (on the margin: years multiply by person - how it say in "developer english" ? - I'm not not native english)

Comment: BD file is not simple text file, stream of characters, and is not rewrittten during updates/deletes. Such understanding is not helpful - its totally diferent. Impossible to safe, bug free etc "manually" patch db files by one person in short time in few lines of C code (I made such few times in career). Use max possible high level access in SQL, good tuning of server (defaults are not so good), use cache, disable flushing

Comment: Your question begins with a false assumption.  You can absolutely modify a file without having to rewrite the entire file.

Comment: If it's not possible to explain it in short then please tell me that are these storage engines made entirely in C/C++ language or do they also use any other language other than that. If so, then which ones?

Comment: Read the manual pages for fseek(), fread(), and fwrite() as a starter.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yes we can modify but we cannot delete some specific text without rewriting the whole file. If you know any other method then can you please tell me?

Comment: Yes you can.  Go read those manual pages.

Comment: almost all classic engines are in C/C++, but this is not helpful. Download sources and rethink You chances

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I know what these functions do. fseek is used to change the position of file pointer. fwrite can be used in this case but it can only be used to REPLACE some text and not delete. I read those manuals earlier.

Comment: Then you already have the answer.  Using fread you read in a sector and fwrite you rewrite that sector.  This is how binary files (like ISAM files) are edited in place without rewriting the entire file.  When an ISAM is modified, it's not like it's a massive text file and one line has been deleted.

Comment: @JacekCz - Does my answer do the "impossible"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as in DOS, things are not "deleted", but rather "marked as deleted" such that to all subsequent operations, the deleted matter seems to be gone.

MyISAM:

- Mark the first byte of the record to indicate that it is "deleted".
- Delete the appropriate entry from each index.

InnoDB:

- Go to the block (in the data BTree, indexed by the `PRIMARY KEY`) contains the row to delete; mark it as deleted.
- Add stuff to the redo/undo log -- in case a subsequent `ROLLBACK` resurrects the row.
- Add an entry to the Change Buffer so that indexed lookups will not find the row.
- Eventually flush the Change Buffer entries to the actual indexes.
- Eventually clear the data record out of the block.

In either engine, there will be only a few IOPs (BTree drilldowns, reads, writes, logging) to delete the row.  The actual number of IOPs depends on caching -- due to combining this delete with other operations on the table.

MyISAM's data is a stream file; the code will "seek" + read or write of the one record.

MyISAM's indexes are BTrees and are cached in the "key_buffer" (1KB blocks); InnoDB's data and indexes are BTrees and are cached in the "buffer_pool" (16KB blocks).  All operations are seek + read/write of one block.

InnoDB redo/undo logs are, I think, streamed.

InnoDB's "double write" buffer is a block that is redundantly written.  This is an ACID protection against a "torn page" wherein a block gets half written during a power outage.  The unit of operation on most disks is a 512-byte "sector"; the unit for MyISAM/InnoDB is several such.

**In the long run**

So, if a record is only marked as deleted, is the *disk* space ever recovered?  I emphasize disk space over "memory" RAM because RAM is just used as a cache.

Well, it depends.  If you are "churning" the data -- deleting and inserting -- then the space freed up by a `DELETE` becomes available for an `INSERT`.  However, because of the way the records are laid out, an `INSERT` may or may not reuse the space recently freed by a `DELETE`.  But, in the long run, inserts will fill in the 'holes' left by deletes.  But...

BTrees inherently have a small problem.  Each node is a fixed size block.  After doing a few deletes, the fixed size has not shrunk.  After doing too many inserts, the block is "split" into two blocks (of the same, fixed, size).  Still, over time, a BTree will gravitate to about 69% full.  That is, what started out as 69 full blocks will (after a lot of churn) reach a steady state of about 100 blocks while still containing the same number of records.

So, *a table* will grow, but never shrink.  But the growth is limited to some factor times the actual data size.  What about shrinking?...

In both MyISAM and InnoDB, there is do automatic way to "defragment" and give back the wasted space to the Operating System.  However, there is an SQL statement to do such.  But don't use it; it is not worth the effort.  It creates a new table, copies all the data over, rebuilds the indexes and renames the table back to what you had.  A lot of effort; almost never much benefit.

Another thing... If two 'adjacent' BTree blocks are less than half full, the blocks will be combined.  (This frees up a block for reuse in the given table, but does not give it back to the OS.)

What do the "large companies" do?  Answer:  "Nothing."  I used to work for such, so I can speak from experience.  In 10,000 tables on 100 systems, I identified *only* 2 cases where defragmentation was worth doing.  And only monthly.  And MyISAM, not InnoDB.  You should not be using MyISAM today.

Comment: So it means that data is not actually deleted but is marked as deleted and skipped from reading. In that case the memory would not be freed up and that would be one of the cons of these storage engines and in the long run it will be required to rewrite the file to free up the memory. Am I right and does this(rewriting once in a long time) really happens in large companies like google and facebook?

Comment: @ChaitanyaVaishampayan - added a long Answer to your Comment